# Opening document from resources in default viewer

Tags: c#, windows-8, resources, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How do I open a document which is included in application's resrouces using a default document viewer installed on a device?

In google I found only examples of opening a document from a file system.

Doing `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)` with uri of format **ms-appx:///Assets/testPdf.pdf** ends in asking to install an application to handle **ms-appx** type resources

Comment: AFAIK you can't open a document directly from resources (this would require the respective default viewer knowing how to access resources) - you need to use a filesystem, i.e. copy the document from resources to a filesystem and open it from there...

Comment: Does this also apply to documents stored in a local database?

Comment: This applies to everything - database, resources, whatever... the default viewer needs to know how to interact with the respective type of storage... usually they all know how to interact with the filesystem, some can work with http(s) - anything else is definitely very specific to that type of viewer (some viewers install special protocol handlers to implement non-standard protocol handling through Launcher).

Answer (score 0):

Simple question. Sorry for this complex answer. Your app gets installed into /Program Files/WindowsApps which has all kinds of security setup by default. As a result, the current user cannot access the folder without being brokered through another user with elevated privileges. In addition, once opened, the user might be tempted to edit and save which would violate the integrity of your app's installation folder, too. In the end, it is what it is - if it makes 100% sense or not.

**But you can do this:**

```
async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file;

    // FAIL: can't read from local package
    folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("Images");
    file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Picture.jpg");
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

    // SUCCESS: can read from local temp folder
    folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
    await file.MoveAsync(folder);
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```

Just move it to your temp folder, which is not protected.

Best of luck!

Comment: It is interesting to me that the FAIL launch does not throw an exception. It just fails and moves on. Sort of misleading, a little.

Comment: I would speculate that the FAIL case potentially throws an exception but since it is Async it might happen on a different thread which perhaps swallows that exception or it brings down the application sometime in the future...

Comment: Well, throwing an uncatchable exception shouldn't count.